# LWC - lightning carousel - not able to use within a for:each loop

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, images

I have a string vector that I'm gettig from js, when this variable has just one element the image is rendered. Below is my code (to work with one element I have to comment template). What is the right way to render images in carousel, maybe I'm missing the key value here.

```
                <template for:each={img} for:item="rec" for:index="index">                  
                    <lightning-carousel-image
                        key= "rec"
                        src={rec.img}
                        header="Image"
                        description="Image"
                        alternative-text="This is a card">
                    </lightning-carousel-image>
                </template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the img src as the key:

```
key={rec.img}
```